# What is the color associated with lukewarm?

Tags: color, color-scheme, color-perception

I'm designing a web application that crowdsources user response to another user's initiative (or project idea). The overall user response to the initiative is represented using a status component with 3 states: Warm, Lukewarm, Cold (a Warm response is a more well-received response).

I'm using #FB6B7B for warm, #45CBE5 for cold. However, I am unsure of what color to use for lukewarm. May I ask what is the color associated with lukewarm in the eyes of the general public?

[image: the 3 states of my status component]

Comment: I am more thrown off by how the "good" response is red. Why not something like positive (green), neutral (gray, maybe), negative (red)?

Comment: @Justin: Because red is associated with higher temperatures, and blue with lower temperatures; thus, it makes sense for "warm" to be red and "cold" to be blue.

Comment: I totally agree with @Justin The very fact that you have this question shows how uncommon and confusing this experience will be for people. I’d reconsider using traffic light colors or something people already understand.

Comment: red is warm, pale red is lukewarm.

Comment: Does it have to be colours?  Could you use the more easily understood thumb-up, thumb-down and thumb-sideways symbols?

Comment: Or old school thermometers combined with whatever color you choose https://images.app.goo.gl/MiFq2egBoRnCUsPH8

Comment: @Sean - I would agree if it were actually about physical temperature. However the OP is only using temperature as a metaphor for user sentiment. This extra layer of metaphor would be fine if it didn't totally reverse the expected position of red from "bad" to "good."

Comment: This question sounds like XY problem. You deal with color for lukewarm, but even if there was an easy and great answer to that, the UI would still be confusing. Traffic light colors sound like a better idea.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I would say "thumb-sideways" isn't super intuitive either, or atleast not widely used. I would instead recommend smiley face :), frowny face :(, and that smiley with the straght line mouth :|. Like [this](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/smiley-icon-outline-set-vector-260nw-526367596.jpg)

Comment: Thing is, if you don't have _any_ "poor" responses, then they're going to look like traffic lights, with STOP and CAUTION. So why not use those universally understood colors? Red=naughty, amber=meh, green=alright.

Comment: I think you should go monochrome with varying Light levels.

Comment: The reason why I am using "warm", "lukewarm", "cold" is because the web application's theme is "Test the waters". After reading your comments, I agree that the UX design is confusing and contrived.
I'm considering use smileys  :)   :|   :( for user response (as suggested by @DasBeasto), and use "warm", "lukewarm", "cold" colors as background color for the smileys (still experimenting). Thanks all for the advice, I'll keep them in mind.

Comment: I also believe that you need to rethink the whole temperature-metaphor ('hotly contested' 'cool idea' 'warm welcome'... temperature is more of an engagement metaphor ('how many votes?', than a metaphor for the direction of the votes 'up/down') but regarding the accepted answer: your Q is still about two very specific polar colors, and a middle ground for those. The accepted A regards a color that feels like the middle ground for very different polar colors - do you really feel #FFE1A5 is good for your chosen colors?

Comment: for me, a sort of slightly lighter than medium-hued greyed blue-green. ew.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Beige

---

Windows 10 has a color temperature meter for Night light.

[image: Win 10 Night Light Color temperature]

Using that as a starting point, I extracted the main colors from the gradient, inverted the colors to extrapolate the 'cool' half of the gradient, and worked this out:

[image: Color Temperature Meter]

On this 5-point scale, `Lukewarm` is **`#FFE1A5`**.

Of course this will change if you change the `Warm` color. The `Cold` color is a complementary color to `Warm` (`#FF6000 <---> #009FFF`, computed using [ColorHexa](https://www.colorhexa.com/ff6000)).

You can use this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w58sj0g1/) to tune the colors to your satisfaction.

Comment: This has the added benefit of playing into the perception of beige as a boring color.

Comment: "Your Neutralness, it's a Beige Alert!"

Answer (score 27):

There isn't really a color associated with lukewarm. As the diagram in [xiota's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/126227/7202) shows, the color association humans have (red = warm, blue = cold) are even the opposite to what you'd expect from a physics point of view.

- Since 'lukewarm' is the neutral option, you could go with a neutral color: **gray**. Do make the button's style different from disabled buttons, if you have any.
- Since 'lukewarm' is the middle option, you could go with the color in between red and blue: **purple**.
- Since 'lukewarm' is presented in the middle, users will know it's the neutral option in between warm and cold **regardless of the color of the button**. Of course, its color shouldn't lean too much to one of the other options; I wouldn't choose another shade of blue or red.

Comment: `(red = warm, blue = cold) are even the opposite to what you'd expect from a physics point of view.` maybe for fire. blue fire is hotter than orange/red fire. But ice is blue which is where I think the "cold" comes from.

Comment: @Brad I don't know where you get your ice, but mine tends to be clear.

Comment: @Tashus Frozen lakes, glaciers, generally really thick ice looks blue. Thin ice like ice cubes isn't thick enough to really notice.

Comment: @Tashus with a small amount, yeah.  With a larger amount you get scattering, making it appear blue - it's the same reason we have a blue sky.

Comment: @Brad: its a plumbing convention: blue for water, red for danger (hot/boiling water). There are other colours for pipes with other things in, such as compressed air.

Comment: @nigel222 I somehow doubt that plumbing is the source of this convention though. Rather they are another adopter of an older convention (fire and ice are older than hot and cold water lines)

Comment: I always assumed the color association comes from the day/night cycle. Ambient outdoor light is "warm" colored midday, and gets cooler towards the evening or on cloudy days.

Comment: I've seen purple quite often

Comment: The reason red is considered hot while blue is considered cold is that hot objects can radiate red light at easily achieved temperatures, while radiating blue light requires extremely high temperatures. Thus, we routinely see red as radiated light, while blue is almost always reflected light.

Comment: It can also be that humans get red when we're hot and blue when we're very cold. There's a lot of ways this association could have become common.

Answer (score 24):

## Violet and Light Green

In color perception theory, at the color wheel there's a division that differentiates warm and cold colors. This division is the one set by violet and light green: above this line the warm and below the cold. Violet and light green have as an attribute that when they are in a warm composition they turn warm and when they are in a cold composition they became cold colors. This lack of definition makes them not warm or cold colors.

[image]

> The colors halfway between these warm and cool extremes, such as yellow-green and red-violet, are fairly neutral; they seem neither very warm nor very cool. The warm and cool qualities of color at this points are very subtle.

From *[Ich werde ein perfekter Künstler. Bd. 2.](https://books.google.es/books?id=8QrBHu9U2bsC&lpg=PA3&ots=lMgeOk95hc&dq=If%20we%20split%20the%20color%20circle%20in%20half%2C%20from%20green%20to%20violet%2C%20we%20make%20a%20division%20between%20warm%20colors%20and%20cold%20colors.%20The%20green%20and%20violet%20can%20be%20part%20both%2C%20depending%20on%20the%20amount%20of%20yellow%20and%20blue%20that%20contains&hl=es&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by John H. Miller, Sonja Steiner-Welz

Comment: What's a good resource for this?

Comment: The color theory has three parts: **optics**, of which you make a very good reference in your answer, **metric**, which corresponds to all systems of color measurement, and **perceptual**, which refers to the incidence of color in our senses. About the latter there are thousands of treatises, a book of theory and perception of color is a good starting point.

Comment: This is not an argument that the "cold" and "warm" terminology applied to colors is the same as how people perceive lukewarm as a temperature or as feedback. This answer appears to conflate the concepts simply because they use the same words, without any reference to actual user testing or UX concepts.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Using the same word would be pretty surprising behavior if the same concept was not intended. I would put the burden of proof on that hypothesis.

Comment: @Grault There's no one "intending" anything here. Language evolves naturally over time, and these three concepts (temperature, colors, sentiment) that happen to share the words "warm" and "cold" could absolutely have arrived at those words by different routes, and have different visual associations. This is all ignoring the inherent cultural aspects of these terms, which may mean that someone from a non-English background wouldn't associate "warm" with "feedback" in any way. The answerer should have data to back up and validate their conclusions.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I don't understand your objection.  No one claims hot and cold colors is the *same* as hot and cold temperature.  But the concepts *are* linked because the same words are associated with both.

Comment: I can second purple, have seen it occasionalls for lukewarm

Comment: I can get on board with purple here depending on the context, but the UX engineer who puts green on a shower knob to indicate lukewarm in the morning is the same UX engineer who's updating his resume in the evening.

Comment: @xiota The *words* are the same. That's a far cry from the visual language being the same, and it doesn't imply that "halfway between warm and cool colors on the color wheel" is going to put in the mind of viewers "halfway between warm and cool in terms of sentiment". This is the logical jump that needs data to validate it.

Comment: @ChrisHayes That makes a lot more sense to me than your previous comments.

Answer (score 20):

I think yellow makes sense for "lukewarm" if red represents "warm" for the reasons called out in [Danielillo's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/126229/127763): "lukewarm" means "moderately warm" and should therefore be represented by a color which is slightly warmer than a neutral green. Magenta would also be an option by this logic, but I think its similarity to hot pink (which literally has "hot" in its name) would make that a confusing choice.

However, I think this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're not actually trying to create a UX to gauge temperature, but sentiment. Does the temperature metaphor hold for all of the cultures that you expect to be present in your userbase? Do those cultures map color to temperature and sentiment in similar enough ways for the colors to make sense to everyone? As an example, red is seen as a negative color in many contexts within the Anglosphere (e.g. "in the red", or "red means stop"), but is largely viewed as positive in Chinese culture. You asked about the perception of "the general public," but that perception depends on their culture, and you didn't mention who "the general public" is in this case. Answering these questions will help you make the correct choice for your userbase.

Comment: Totally agree with it being an XY problem - and that it suggests the OP and team have no experience of actually running surveys. A competently-phrased survey proposal can be answered by "agree", "disagree" or "no opinion". For more accurate results, the survey can provide gradations of "agree" and "disagree". The OP's proposal though is missing all of this.

Comment: I'm using "warm", "lukewarm", "cold" in attempt to fit with the web application's theme - "Test the waters". After reading all the responses, I agree that I need to modify my solution. I still foresee using the warm, lukewarm, cold colors somewhere in my web app. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 10):

How did you decide on cool vs warm? It can be problematic because the interpretation of red is opposite what some people expect, as others have noted.

- I often see responses color coded **green-yellow-red**. It seems to work well without explanation, probably because people are familiar with **traffic lights**. (Even if the lights aren't necessarily *green*, people still *think* of them as green, like tennis balls and US dollars.)
- What you have seems like it could work well enough. Consider using it along with a thermometer illustration.

  [image: thermometer]
- [Kaz](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/126302/115162) describes how car temperature controls indicate temperature. Similar solutions are used in some home thermostats and water faucets.

  [image: Car A/C]
- **ROYGBIV** is used in some weather forecasts

  [image: weather forecast]
- There is a **[color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) scale** that runs along a **blue-red spectrum** that is commonly used to adjust white balance on cameras. Notice that blue is hotter, while red is cooler. **Intermediate colors are white, yellow, orange.**

  [image: color temperature]

Comment: "green-yellow-red... seems to work well without explanation" Unless you're colour-blind.

Comment: That's why words or numbers are associated with responses.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The "green" in traffic lights is actually closer to a bright turquoise or cyan in order to account for color blindness. It's also outside the RGB gamut.

Comment: @Locoluis The blue is particularly striking in Japan, where perceived hues are blue-shifted compared to the Anglosphere. Traffic lights are [red, yellow/amber, and "bleen"/"grue"](https://99percentinvisible.org/article/stop-at-red-go-on-grue-how-language-turned-traffic-lights-bleen-in-japan/).

Answer (score 5):

As a start, I think if the targeted data related to **Temperature** the **Lukewarm color = purple** the midway between red and blue as I'll state that now.

The best colors to pick are ONLY "**Red and Blue**" which represent clearly the temperature, so any change in the temperature will vary between these two color values by using a gradient to show the change in the degree. as in the listed image as an example.

One of the main general rules in usability: **More data representations will confuse the user** instead of letting him focus. Because you use colors to get his attraction, but more than that he will go to values and neglect the chart or the graphics thing.

You can read about **Mapbox GL** which is a suite of open-source libraries for embedding highly customizable and responsive client-side maps in Web, mobile, and desktop applications.

Maybe it's not related to your track of work, but you will get an idea of how to use the heat map and color representations well. Read more to narrow your choices!

[image]

This is a temperature map, took it from the net:
You can refer to that image from this useful article I used to read recently
https://blog.ndustrial.io/temperature-gradient-maps-with-mapbox-gl-9f97fb44d5f2

Comment: I totally agree, and I've seen dark purple being used for "not hot, not cold" meaning.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's instructive to [look at passenger vehicle AC/heater controls](https://www.google.com/search?q=car+heater+control&tbm=isch). These often come in the form of a circular dial whose opposite ranges are denoted red and blue. How they treat the middle between them falls into several patterns:

- no "lukewarm" zone: abrupt transition from blue to red, with perhaps a small gap.
- no "lukewarm" color, but a somewhat larger gap.
- "faux cross-fade" from red to blue with overlap: one stripe is narrowing as the other widens.
- "faux cross-fade" with coarse-grained dithering: the stripes are chopped up and blended, with cuts of one color getting longer as the others get shorter.
- The stripes meet, or nearly meet, without overlap, but get thinner toward the center meeting point.
- The "lukewarm" zone is indicated as a white stripe.  Sometimes the blue/white/red arcs are of about equal length. Sometimes white is significantly more than 1/3rd of the range, sometimes significantly less.

I'm unable to find a picture of a design that uses a third color other than white or else transparent (whatever the background/substrate color is).

In a computer UI I'd probably make a gradient from red to white to blue, or from red to transparent/background to blue, or else imitate the above ideas.

Answer (score 3):

### Magenta

When you mix blue and red light, as opposed to pigments, you get magenta.

Also, subjectively, it feels like a “lukewarm” color to me.

[image: Magenta]

Comment: Aside from the top centre and bottom centre those are all very strong colours, hardly what I'd associate with lukewarmness at all. Can you explain more why you think they're appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

All the physics arguments are irrelevant, the average user doesn't have a clue about colour temperatures. But drawing a line on a hue-lightness colour wheel between red and cold-water blue might give you a clue. It passes through a pale pink with a slightly more mauve hue than the red. That would probably be a good lukewarm colour. Hot and cold cancelling, but with enough warmth left to notice.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a perfect example of bias. The requirement was "how to show a user response".  But the choice/"solution" given was an assumed solution - the use of color to show user response.  The correct approach should be, how to best show the user response - thumbs up/sideways/down might be a correct approach- they symbolize approval/disapproval.